# How do I alter a variable in a function using another function that resides within the former function?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, depth-first-search

The language I'm using is Python and I'm trying to solve a DFS algorithm problem using a function called Solution. In this case, the code will show as follows:

```
def dfs(row, column, value):
    if row == R and column == C:
        answer = max(answer, value)
        return
    new_row = row + ~~
    new_column = column + ~~
    dfs(new_row, new_column, value + board[new_row][new_column])

def solution(board):
    answer = 0
    dfs(0, 0, 0)
    return answer

print(solution(board))
```

So in this case, I'm trying to use a function called dfs to examine a 2 dimensional array called board. When the location (defined by the two variables called row and column) reaches the destination, I need to alter the answer variable that exists inside the solution function, and I have no idea how I can do that.

If the answer variable existed outside the function, I would have used global method to change the answer variable, but in this case it is impossible to do so.

Hope the experts here can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: What is `~~`? Your search seems to not have any choice, it just goes in a predefined direction (depending on what `~~` is supposed to do).

Comment: **"**_DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]_**"**

Comment: You obviously know about ``return`` and function parameters, since you are using both. Why does ``dfs`` not ``return answer``, and take its initial value as an argument?

Comment: Just found out that I can use the nonglobal on answer variable inside the dfs and set the dfs function inside the solution function to manipulate answer variable of the solution function. The reason I don't use ```return answer``` in the dfs function is because there is a chance that I get multiple outcomes from dfs.